# Filepath in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript

I am setting a file path in java as follows,

```
String requestedFileName = param+File.separator+fileName;
request.setAttribute("requestedFileName",requestedFileName);
```

and i am retreving it in javascript as follows,

```
var selectedFileName = null;
if ('${requestScope.requestButtonParam}' == "convert") {
   selectedFileName = '${requestScope.requestedFileName}';          
   alert("inside if: "+selectedFileName);
}
```

But in the alert box,i am getting file path as below
**D:NewFolderAbc.html** instead of **D://NewFolder//Abc.html**

How to get the filepath correctly in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Use:

<%selectedFileName  = request.getParameter("requestedFileName"); %>

Now print it out an see what its giving  yah .

Comment: Have you logged the value of requestedFileName on the server? Also, File.separator will return the separator used on the server OS. It might not be right for the client.

Comment: I think its browser related

Answer (score -1):

The trouble is most likely that your `File.separator` is `\` which is an escape character in Javascript, so you're going to have to escape the escape character.

An easy way of doing the escaping is using Apache Commons [StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String requestedFileName = param+File.separator+fileName;
String escapedFileName = StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(requestedFileName);
request.setAttribute("requestedFileName",escapedFileName);
```

This will change `D:\NewFolder\Abc.html` to `D:\\NewFolder\\Abc.html` which then gets correctly interpreted in your Javascript.